# How do I calculate the minimum deflection I can sense with a strain gauge, like the BF350-3AA?

Tags: sensor, measurement, strain-gage

I have a strain gauge (the BF350-3AA), and I will be connecting it to an HX711-based amplifier sensor.

From [its low-quality datasheet](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81syDCHm59L.pdf), I've pulled out the following figures:

1. Nominal Resistance: 350 ohms
2. Sensitivity Coefficient (which I believe is also called the Gauge Coefficient): 2.1
3. Sensitivity Coefficient Dispersion: <+/- 1%
4. Transverse Effect Coefficient: 0.4%
5. Strain Limit: 2%

Ultimately, the quantity that I want to measure is the number of micrometers of deflection over the length of the gauge. What is the minimum sensitivity (or precision) of deflection I can measure?

The gauge is being deployed inside a long flexure block of concrete, with its normal parallel to the axis of the press.

Bonus question: What formula do I use to calculate the deflection as a function of resistance (or resistance change)?

Comment: More information is needed to determine the displacement from the stain. What does the structure look like? What does the loading look like? Where is the gage located on the structure?

Comment: The gauge is being deployed inside a long flexure block of concrete, with its normal parallel to the axis of the press. Updated in post.

Answer (score 1):

There are several limits to the smallest useful deflection.

One is given by the noise of the system. That varies with the amplifier/ADC that follows the strain gauge, and the bandwidth you are using. The noise level allows you to get a strain via the listed sensitivity.

Even if you use a very quiet amplifier to get a very small observable strain, the long term drift of the gauge, its mechanical hysteresis, and its resetability, will all limit whether the ability to measure such a small strain is actually useful.

At that low level, the gauge resistance is unlikely to contribute meaningfully to the noise of the system, unless you are using a very low noise op amp indeed. I would expect the mechanical parameters to dominate the limits.